# Failed to generate iOS ipa file

Tags: release, c++builder, testflight

I followed the instruction here:

[Deploying Your iOS Application for Submission to the App Store](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Submission_to_the_App_Store)

Failed when Step 4:

> Select Project > Deployment, and click the Deploy button to deploy your application.

It is suppose to generate an `.ipa` file, but I got the following error messages:

```
paclient command line for "Dell_Macbook_Air"
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\paclient.exe -u8 --ipa="ESF RC1.app,ESF RC1.ipa,'Apple Distribution: Courant Tseng 
  (LB289US7N2)','/Users/Courant/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/49871f08-e3ef-4ef6-9cef-2756304c93c1.mobileprovision',2" Dell_Macbook_Air 

[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2021-10-12 17:18:30.006 xcodebuild[1464:20952] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/wm/8hg70w3n355g3qsc5k9z34hh0000gn/T/ESF RC1_2021-10-12_17-18-30.002.xcdistributionlogs'.

[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 Exported ESF RC1 to: /Users/Courant/PAServer/scratch-dir/Courant-Dell_Macbook_Air/ESF RC1.archive/temp

[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 ** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **
Failed
```

Can anyone give some advise to solve the problem so that I can send it to App Store (Testflight)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer from Embarcadero Customer Support Center.

This "error" is connected with the CFBundleName/CFBundleDisplayName. If these parameters in the project's project option contains space characters, this error will occur.

I removed the spcace character off mu app name (ESF RC1--> ESF_RC1)
It works.

BTW, according to them, the bug had been fixed in Rad Studio 11.